# Destringing a list of variables

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am trying to write some code in R for others to use who are in the field at my company.  I need a generic code where they can create a list of variables within a dataset that are stored as strings, and then run a command to destring all variables in that list at once.  I know how I would do this using the `TaRifx` package, but I'm not sure how to make this code as generic and user-friendly as possible

Comment: What does "restring all variables" mean to you? Can you give a small example with input and desired output?

Comment: sorry, "destring" - I'll correct that typo. restring means nothing to me but destring means making values numeric (as you know)

Comment: `data[cols] = lapply(data[cols], as.numeric)`

Comment: Thats helpful, but can I put a list of variables into this command? ```stringvars <- list("var1", "var2")
data[stringvars] = lapply(data[stringvars], as.numeric) ``` I don't think that works? Ideally, I could simply tell the people who use this code "fill in the variables on the list command, and then run this command to destring everything within the list.

Comment: Why would you use a `list` instead of a character vector for column names? If you use `stringvars <- c("var1", "var2")` it will work just fine. [I'm a big fan of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207), but don't use lists when vectors will do.

Comment: If you really need a list, you can just `unlist` it first, `data[unlist(stringvars)] = lapply(data[unlist(stringvars)], as.numeric)`. That will work with lists or character vectors, assuming the list is reducible to a character vector by `unlist()`...

Comment: You could also use `dplyr`, which is often easier to introduce new people to than base R, e.g., `data <- data %>% mutate(across(all_of(stringvars), as.numeric))`. It will also expect a character vector, so use `unlist()` if you insist on lists.

Comment: You're totally right. Been in stata lately rather than R, and in stata, a "varlist" of variables acts like a vector in R. thanks for helping me knock some rust off.